# Creating table at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I'm new to databases and I'm not sure how to handle this situation. I have 3 tables connected this way:

```
Session   <- 1:1 ->   Document   <- 1:1 ->   DocumentData
```

So basically there is always 1 `Session` that has a `Document` which has a `DocumentData`.

I want to be able to add different types and columns of data to `DocumentData`, so for example I can have `DocumentData` with 3 columns of type `DateTime`,`Int32`,`Int32`. And then have another table with 5 columns of types `Datetime`,`double`,`Int32`,`Int32`,`Int32`. Basically what I'm going for is to have something like this in my code:

```
using(var unit = new UnitOfWork(new SessionContext()))
{
    var data = unit.Sessions.GetCurrent().Document.DocumentData;    
    var row = data.Column[0].Rows[5]... etc.
}
```

This is because `DocumentData` is generated from csv specified by a user, so each `DocumentData` is made of different columns.

**EDIT:**
I want to know how to create a table on runtime and assign whatever columns I want to it. So I want to be able to do something like:

```
var doc = new Document();
session.Document = doc;
doc.Columns.Add(new Column() {Rows = rows});
doc.Columns.Add(new Column() {Rows = rows2});
doc.SaveChanges();
```

and then have second table with different columns.

**EDIT2:**
To make it more clear I want to convert this:

```
public class DocumentData {
  public List<DocumentColumn> Columns { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentColumn {
  public string ColumnName { get; set; }
  public List<object> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

into ado.net entities so I can save them to database.

Comment: I'm really struggling to find a question here. What is your problem?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL statement to create tables at runtime (via dbcontext). I don't think that its possible to bind such a table to an entity / class at runtime after the database / context is initialized.

But if you don't have to use the different / variable columns as query / selection parameters, simply serialize the document class in a single BLOB column and your done.